# Why my application do not fire all scheduled notification?

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

I am working on application that fire a scheduled notification.

What i am facing is that not all the scheduled notifications are fired.

In my example, sometimes it only fire the last notification(event4) sometimes it fire the 1st,3rd, and the 4th notification skipping the 2nd.
why is that happening?

this is my code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE,26);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.set(Calendar.DATE,26);
        cal2.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);
        cal2.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);
        cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

        Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal3.set(Calendar.DATE,26);
        cal3.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        cal3.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        cal3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);
        cal3.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

        Calendar cal4 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal4.set(Calendar.DATE,26);
        cal4.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        cal4.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        cal4.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);
        cal4.set(Calendar.SECOND, 40);



AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

 Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);

        alertIntent.putExtra("Notification Key", 1);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        alertIntent.putExtra("Notification Key", 2);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        alertIntent.putExtra("Notification Key", 3);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        alertIntent.putExtra("Notification Key", 4);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal4.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 4, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

and this is the `OnReceive`

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     Integer notificationId  = intent.getIntExtra("Notification Key", -1);
    switch(notificationId){
        case 1:
            createNotification(context, "title1", "event1", "event of today");
            break;
        case 2:
            createNotification(context, "title2", "event2", "event of today");
            break;
        case 3:
            createNotification(context, "title3", "event3", "event of today");
            break;
        case 4:
            createNotification(context, "title4", "event4", "event of today");
            break;
    }


       }

public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert) {
    PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.not)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setTicker(msgAlert)
            .setContentText(msgText);
    //intent to fire when notification clicked on
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
    //how the person will be notified
    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    //cancel notification when clicked in the taskbar
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

notification id should not be unique for issued notifications

```
  mNotificationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build());
```

change the above code like

```
  mNotificationManager.notify(some_random_number++,mBuilder.build());
```

use any random number .. you can use below script to generate random number

```
 Random rand = new Random2();
 randomNum = minimum + rand.nextInt((maximum - minimum) + 1);
```

Comment: how could i generate a unique number each time?  you mean making a simple for loop? and use "i" instead of constant number?

Comment: @ygz82 yeah.. simply pass different numbers while issueing notification

Comment: i tried it, but still messy, the first time it runs good, but for the next times at cal2 the 1st and 2nd notification was fired, and at cal4 the 3rd and 4th notification was fired. i tried to generate unique random number, and its the same still messy, i got 3 notifications fired at the same time with cal3, and cal4 was fired at next minute

Comment: i tried it another time, all the 4 notifications were fired with the cal4, i mean with the last notification

Comment: so editing the notification ID is just if you want to store a reference for your notification in order to return to it in the future, in my case i dont need a reference to the notification, i just need to display it, so there is no need to generate new number , 0 default is okay, and let each notification replace the previous , no problem, so the problem i think is somewhere else